# Using Arrays.sort() and Arrays.binarySearch() for a list of integers stored in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search

What i'm trying to do is, take user input for a number N of integers, then use `Arrays.sort()` to sort the list of integers and then perform `Arrays.binarySearch()` to search for a particular integer in the array.

I'm getting some weird output for the `Arrays.sort()` and for the `Arrays.binarySearch()` it's returning true even for numbers which is not found in the array.

**CODES:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Number2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=0;

    System.out.print("Enter the number of integers: ");
    n = input.nextInt();

    int[] numbers = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter integer #"+(i+1)+": ");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    Arrays.sort(numbers);

    System.out.println("After sorting: "+numbers);

    System.out.println("Enter a number to search for: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, num);

    if(index > -1)
    {
        System.out.println("The value "+num+" exist in the array");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("The value "+num+" exist in the array");
    }
}

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to overwrite comparator or comparable to sort it in your way .. and the weird output is your object memory .. `toString()` method should be overridden to print value

Answer (score 2):

This is the `toString()` implementation of array object, you are looking for [`Arrays#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])), which is implemented to actually show you the elements in the array.

```
 System.out.println("After sorting: "+ Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Answer (score 2):

Are You sure it misbehaves?

try changing this :

```
else
{
    System.out.println("The value "+num+" exist in the array");
}
```

to this

```
else
{
    System.out.println("The value "+num+" DOES NOT exist in the array");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You should use `Arrays.toString()` to print the `numbers`.

2.`Arrarys.binarySearch()` returns index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, returns (-(insertion point) - 1), insertion point is the index at which the key would be inserted into the array. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found. So you should change your `else` statement.